# Notepad++ search and replace

Tags: notepad++, notepad

I really need a quick help.

Can someone tell me how to find and replace for example:

```
<a href="blab34345.html">Apple</a><br />
<a href="bl44abla123415646.html">Pear</a><br />
<a href="blabla12354134.html">lemon</a><br />
```

into:

```
<a href="blabla.html">Apple</a><br />
<a href="blabla.html">Pear</a><br />
<a href="blabla.html">lemon</a><br />
```

Thank you ! :)

Comment: Don't think you can do that in notepad. This would be pretty straight forward in excel though.

Comment: Don't let CTRL + F get in your way in Notepad++. There is a replace feature there that will come in handy.

Comment: just use Ctrl+H..,in any normal text editor,

Comment: I think they're looking for a RegEx based search and replace feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Notepad++ you can do it easily using regular expressions. Go to `Search > Replace` menu (shortcut <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>) and do the following:

1. Find what:

   ```
   a href="\K.+?(?=\.html")
   ```
2. Replace:

   ```
   blabla
   ```
3. Select radio button "Regular Expression"
4. Then press `Replace All`

You can test it and see the results for your specific example at [regex101](http://regex101.com/r/oN6nD6).

Answer (score 0):

In Notepad++, ctrl+h brings up the replace menu. I do not know if there is a character limit, but that should be all you need.

Answer (score 0):

Notepad++ sometimes get wrong results when using variables like $var but most of the times with tags doesn't happen, so simple as pressing ctrl + H gets you the replace tab and search for the string.

Or as @Mike Christensen said are you looking for a regular expression solution?